# how to add key value pair in dictionary at index using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries which look like

```
   print(data)
```

gives output

```
[ 
    {   "id" : "1",
        "emp_name" : "xyz",
        "emp_dob" : "01-10-1995",
        "emp_salary" : "35000"
    },
    {   "id" : "2",
        "emp_name" : "abc",
        "emp_dob" : "01-11-1994",
        "emp_salary" : "35000"
    },
  ]
```

In above list of dictionaries I want to add new key value pair("comp_address":"xyz road") after emp_name and before emp_dob, So resulted dictionary should look like as follows:

```
print(data)
```

Output

```
[ 
    {   "id" : "1",
        "emp_name" : "xyz",
        "comp_address":"xyz road"
        "emp_dob" : "01-10-1995",
        "emp_salary" : "35000"
    },
    {   "id" : "2",
        "emp_name" : "abc",
        "comp_address":"xyz road"
        "emp_dob" : "01-11-1994",
        "emp_salary" : "35000"
    },
  ]
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

```py
for indx in range(len(dc['data'])):
    dc['data'][indx]['comp_address'] = 'xyz road'
```

Comment: Can you explain me how it is working